# Powershell command from batch file not working as expected

Tags: batch-file, powershell-1.0

I am running a batch script, but I get an error stating that

`-command is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I am not able to understand why. I also looked at my environmental variable path. That looks to be fine.

Below is the Script

```
@echo off 
set PWSH = %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
%PWSH% -command $input ^| %1\post-commit-jenkins.ps1 %1 %2   
pause 
if errorlevel 1 exit %errorlevel%
```

Please provide your opinion and possible solution .

Comment: npocmaka already provided the solution, but to explain *why*: `%PWSH%` is empty, because the variable you defined is `%PWSH %`. Remove `Echo off` to watch...

Comment: It may help were you to explain what you expect `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command $input ^| %1\post-commit-jenkins.ps1 %1 %2` to do!

Comment: Very doubtful that you are using Powershell version 1 these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
set "PWSH=%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
%PWSH% -command $input ^| %1\post-commit-jenkins.ps1 %1 %2   
pause 
if errorlevel 1 exit %errorlevel%
```

Remove the space when you are setting a otherwise because it will be part of the variable name (not I have no idea what are the %1 and %2 arguments so I don't know what to expect further )